# How do i keep sharp edges after combining 2 high poly sculpted meshes?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting, sculpt

Not sure how to fix this shading issues and still keep the sharp angles. I found that smoothing tool helps but i loose those angles then. Does anyone know alternative to this?[image: i need that area to look clean but still have that same angle]

Comment: are these two parts part of the same mesh?

Comment: Yes, I connected them with boolean modifier.